Modifying linked IFC in Revit using C#
I'm working on an automation project in Visual Studio using C#, but I still have limited experience and lack a lot of knowledge. revit errorThe script manage to download the IFC file and reload it using transactions, but it doesn't modify anything, and Revit shows me the message in the attached image. I'm also including the part of the code where I perform the transactions because I believe that's where I'm making mistakes. I really appreciate any help. Regards.
This is the part of the script to make a transaction on the linked IFC:
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
public class FillGeoPar : IExternalCommand
{
public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
{
UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
Document doc = uidoc.Document;
Application app = uiapp.Application;
        try
        {
            // Obtener el diccionario de documentos vinculados IFC
            RevitLinkChecker linkChecker = new RevitLinkChecker();
            var diccDocsVinc = linkChecker.ObtenerDiccVincReload(doc, "ifc");

            // Mostrar TaskDialog con los vínculos cargados
            string vinculosCargados = string.Join("\n", diccDocsVinc.Keys);
            TaskDialog.Show("Vínculos Cargados", $"Los siguientes vínculos IFC están cargados:\n{vinculosCargados}");

            // Seleccionar archivo Excel
            string dfRuta = SeleccionarArchivoExcel();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dfRuta))
            {
                message = "No se seleccionó ningún archivo Excel.";
                return Result.Cancelled;
            }

            // Seleccionar hoja del Excel
            string dfHoja = SeleccionarHojaExcel(dfRuta);
            if (dfHoja == null)
            {
                message = "No se seleccionó ninguna hoja de Excel.";
                return Result.Cancelled;
            }

            // Obtener DataFrame del Excel
            var df = ObtenerDataFrameExcel(dfRuta, dfHoja);
            if (df == null)
            {
                message = "No se pudo obtener la hoja del archivo Excel.";
                return Result.Failed;
            }

            // Mostrar la primera columna en un diálogo
            var primeraColumna = df.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row[0].ToString()).ToList();
            TaskDialog.Show("Primera Columna", string.Join("\n", primeraColumna));

            // Descargar todos los vínculos fuera de la transacción
            var loadedExternalFilesRef = new List<RevitLinkType>();
            var collector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
            foreach (Element element in collector.OfClass(typeof(RevitLinkType)))
            {
                ExternalFileReference extFileRef = element.GetExternalFileReference();
                if (extFileRef == null || extFileRef.GetLinkedFileStatus() != LinkedFileStatus.Loaded)
                    continue;

                var revitLinkType = (RevitLinkType)element;
                loadedExternalFilesRef.Add(revitLinkType);
                revitLinkType.Unload(null);
            }

            // Reabrir los vínculos y modificar parámetros
            foreach (var revitLinkType in loadedExternalFilesRef)
            {
                // Obtener la ruta del archivo vinculado
                ExternalFileReference extFileRef = revitLinkType.GetExternalFileReference();
                string rutaVinc = ModelPathUtils.ConvertModelPathToUserVisiblePath(extFileRef.GetAbsolutePath());

                // Abrir el documento del vínculo
                Document linkDoc = app.OpenDocumentFile(rutaVinc);

                // Verificar y asignar los parámetros de los elementos vinculados que coinciden con las columnas del Excel
                using (Transaction trans = new Transaction(linkDoc, "Modificar Parámetros Elementos Vinculados"))
                {
                    trans.Start();

                    var nombresColumnasIFC = VerificarColumnasIFC(diccDocsVinc, df, linkDoc);

                    var colector = new FilteredElementCollector(linkDoc)
                        .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
                        .ToList();

                    foreach (var element in colector)
                    {
                        IList<Parameter> parametros = element.GetOrderedParameters();
                        Parameter nombreCodigoParam = parametros.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Definition != null && p.Definition.Name.Contains("NombreCódigo"));

                        if (nombreCodigoParam != null)
                        {
                            string nombreCodigo = nombreCodigoParam.AsString();

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nombreCodigo) && primeraColumna.Contains(nombreCodigo))
                            {
                                DataRow filaExcel = df.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(row => row[0].ToString() == nombreCodigo);

                                if (filaExcel != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (Parameter param in parametros)
                                    {
                                        if (param.Definition != null)
                                        {
                                            string paramName = param.Definition.Name;

                                            string columna = nombresColumnasIFC.FirstOrDefault(col => paramName.EndsWith(col, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

                                            if (columna != null && df.Columns.Contains(columna))
                                            {
                                                string valorExcel = filaExcel[columna].ToString();

                                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valorExcel))
                                                {
                                                    if (param.StorageType == StorageType.String)
                                                    {
                                                        param.Set(valorExcel);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (param.StorageType == StorageType.Double && double.TryParse(valorExcel, out double valorDouble))
                                                    {
                                                        param.Set(valorDouble);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (param.StorageType == StorageType.Integer && int.TryParse(valorExcel, out int valorInt))
                                                    {
                                                        param.Set(valorInt);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (param.StorageType == StorageType.ElementId && int.TryParse(valorExcel, out int valorElementId))
                                                    {
                                                        param.Set(new ElementId(valorElementId));
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    trans.Commit();
                }

                // Cerrar el documento del vínculo
                linkDoc.Close(false);

                // Recargar el vínculo
                revitLinkType.Load();
            }

            // Regenerar el documento principal
            doc.Regenerate();

            TaskDialog.Show("Éxito", "Parámetros modificados y guardados correctamente.");
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
            return Result.Failed;
        }
    }

The script I'm trying to develop involves creating an add-in for Revit, which, with a linked IFC file, establishes a relationship between data from an Excel table and parameters of elements within this IFC file, attempting to modify these parameters with the data from the table.

Your code is long and hard to understand. The error message clearly indicates that you are attempting to modify the document outside a transaction. You have one transaction in there, but some modifications are happening outside of the transaction scope. I suggest you clean up your code and split it into smaller separate logical units to make it easier to understand the logic.

Hi Jeremy, nice to meet you. Thanks a lot for the advice and suggestion, I will try to do it that way. I don't have much experience in programming yet and it's hard for me. What I want to achieve is that by accessing the IFC, relating one of the columns of an excel that has the same values ​​as the name of one of the attributes of each element, take the rest of the values ​​of the columns and fill the empty parameters of the IFC elements with the data from the rest of the columns. At least the methods and steps to follow to access the IFC, download it and reload it are those?

Your approach looks OK to me. You might also want to take a look at the Lab4_2_ExportParametersToExcel sample in the ADN Xtra labs. It exports all parameters for each element for all Revit categories, one Excel sheet per category, one column per parameter.

By the way, if you are only interested in IFC files, why use a commercial proprietary product Revit, and not an open-source IFC library instead?

Hi Jeremy, thank you so much for the documentation.
The reason I am trying to modify the IFC parameters through a link in Revit is because I need to create the button so that any other user can run it and select the Excel file where the data is located in order to update the IFC and then export everything and federate the model. I have modified the code and organized it, but I cannot get the new values ​​to be added to the IFC.

Well, if the IFC file is linked in, I doubt that you will be able to modify it. You will need to open the original in order to change anything.

Ok, so I'll try to make the modification before it is linked and once done, try to link it. Would that be possible?
